# How to save logfile in non-volatile memory

Tags: shell-script, embedded, syslog, busybox

I have an embedded device with NAND flash as rootfs. Logfiles are kept in RAM, as they are usually boring and must not wear out the flash. But seldom the devices enters a defective state which I need to debug. So on error, I copy `/var/log/messages` to the NAND in a shell script (busybox bash).

So far, so good. Unfortunally, if there is one error, it's likely to produce hundreds or even thousands of crashes before the watchdog ist going to reboot the system. I like to investigate the logfile as close to the crash as possible, bit I don't want to copy the entire logfile thousands of times, but rather copy it one time and then append all new messages to that file.

How would you do that? I can think of storing a line counter and if the file already exists, append only lines after the line counter (and update the line counter afterwards), but maybe there is a more intelligent way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In the same error handling code in which you copy the file, couldn't you also start a background process that uses `tail -f` to append subsequent lines to the copied log file? Something like:

```bsh
tail -c +$(( $(wc -c COPIED_LOG | awk '{print $1}')+1 )) -f /var/log/messages >> COPIED_LOG
```

where `COPIED_LOG` is the path of wherever you stored the copied log file. `tail` is instructed with `-c +N` to start outputting at the `N`-th byte encountered in `/var/log/messages`, for which I here use the number of bytes already in the copied file (`wc -c COPIED_LOG | awk '{print $1}'`) plus one to get to the byte at which the new content starts. This is then appended to `COPIED_LOG` using `>>`.

You'd have to wrap this in `nohup ... &` or something like that to make it run as a background process. Also, as you already said in your question, check whether `COPIED_LOG` already exists and only run this background process if it doesn't.